# Including a particular function from a source file

Tags: sourcecode

I know I can use the `listings` package to include specific lines of a source file in my document, but is there any option or package that would allow me to specify a particular function to include instead?

Comment: Particular function of what? Are we still talking inclusion of source code? You can probably get away with adding special comments in the source and then including according to them. Specifically including a given function from a source file, require knowledge of the language the source is written in and is this outside the realm of LaTeX and friends.

Comment: See section 6.7 in the `listings` manual, http://texdoc.net/pkg/listings